# Steam set user status

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Is there any possibility to set the own steam status via the web api or something else?
I found only a get functionality with [GetPlayerSummaries](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're out of luck, since the Steam Web API is only to get data from steam for various objectives (data mining and analysis mostly), not to apply changes to an account.

https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=english

> Valve provides these APIs so website developers can use data from Steam in new and interesting ways. They allow developers to query Steam for information that they can present on their own sites.

Comment: That was useful info. I was trying to set user info with the api with no success. My question is then what is the function of the API "change_status(**kwargs)" for? As far as I understand seems to be just for that, not working thought. Find func documentation link : https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.client.html#steam.client.SteamClient.change_status thanks a lot